# Union de dos consultas mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito realizar la union de estas dos tablas de mysql 
Esta es mi primera consulta

```
SELECT pr_funds.fund
FROM pr_funds
WHERE pr_funds.type = 'AFP'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi segunda consulta

```
SELECT pr_employees.afp_id, COUNT(*) as totalPersonal, pr_funds.fund
FROM pr_employees
LEFT JOIN pr_funds on pr_funds.fund = pr_employees.afp_id
 = pr_employees.afp_id
where pr_employees.status = 1 and pr_employees.afp_id != 'null'
group by pr_employees.afp_id
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que fund aparezca en la segunda consulta, ya que trato de hacer un left join pero lo manda null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Con la segunda consulta debería ser suficiente, pero la condición del LEFT JOIN está mal:

```
LEFT JOIN pr_funds on pr_funds.fund = pr_employees.afp_id = pr_employees.afp_id
```

Debes corregirlo porque estás tratando de comparar, por un lado, el mismo campo (código repetido). Por otro, seguramente devuelva NULL porque no hay relación entre el campo *fund* (un string con el nombre) y el campo *afp_id* (un entero).

Entiendo que lo más probable es que haya un id en la tabla *pr_funds* que pueda igualar al campo *afp_id* de la tabla *pr_employees*. Algo tipo:

```
LEFT JOIN pr_funds ON pr_funds.afp_id = pr_employees.afp_id
```

En cualquier caso, el problema está en esa parte del código: Revisa la relación entre las tablas y arregla la comparación repetida (pr_employees.afp_id = pr_employees.afp_id).

Comment: Porque pones doble ves el on?

Comment: Perdón, puse mal el código en la explicación, ya está corregido para asemejarlo al código que originalmente habías puesto.

Comment: Gracias!, tu respuesta fue de mucha ayuda